# ${WORKSPACE_PATH} Vanished

Tags: xcode4

I was developing a "*pre-action"* for the *"build"* phase of my project. I was quite happily using the:

```
${WORKSPACE_PATH}
```

...environment variable, but then all of a sudden it stopped working, printing the list of variables to a file shows it has vanished:

```
printenv > ~/Desktop/xcode-envs.txt
```

I'm completely stumped.

Comment: $(PROJECT_DIR)/../otherProjectPath/ will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as of 4.0.1, WORKSPACE_PATH was removed from the pre- and post-action script environments. I'm not sure where Apple is going with the pre/post action scripts but this taken with "where the hell did the output go?" makes them all but useless.

See [this Apple Developer Forum thread](https://devforums.apple.com/message/407625#407625) for reference if you have access.